# Hide Columns Based on parameter value not working in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a `SSRS report` which have N number of Columns. I need to hide Certain `columns` based on a parameter "jobcode" .  I have tried below `expression` in `Column Visibility` Pane,

```
=iif(Parameters!JobCode.Value=1,"False","True")
```

While Executing the report I got below Error,

> "The Hidden Expression used in the tablix 'Tablix1' returned a
>   datatype that is not valid"

I have tried like below,

```
=iif(Parameters!JobCode.Value=1,0,1)
```

But, got the same error. Can Anyone help me to find out answers for below queries

1. How to achieve the above requirement in `ssrs`?
2. If I need hide column based on multiple parameter values, say 0 and 1, How to do it?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If JobCode = 0 , Show

```
   =IIF(CInt(Fields!JobCode.Value) = 0,true,false)
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps:**

*Right click in your column>Column Visibility>Show or hide based on an expression*

**Expression, use that:**

> =Parameters!parameter_name.Value<>1